# TypeError: dates.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, array.prototype.map

I am making an app in node.js, in local test works but when deploy an AWS I get this error "dates.map is not a function".

I leave the code where I get error. Thank you.

```
 module.exports = function (ctx, dates) {

 console.log(dates);
 var authenticated = yo`<div class="container timeline cont-estadisticas">
 <div id="top-menu" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="tabs-menu-redes">
      <li class="current"><a href="#facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="#instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>Instagram</a></li>
      <li><a href="#twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>Twitter</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="stadistitics-container" class="cont-redes tab-content">
  <div id="facebook" class="row tab-content-redes" style="display:block" >
    ${dates.map(function (dato){
      if(dato.userId === ctx.auth.username){
        hay = buscardatosfb(ctx, dates, dato);
        if(hay === 1){
          hay = 0;
          ++mostrardatosfb
          if(mostrardatosfb === 1){
            return yo``
                      }
                    })}
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="cont-meses">
              ${dates.map(function (dato){
                if(dato.userId === ctx.auth.username & dato.red === 'fb'){
                  if(dato.type === 'year'  ){
                    return vistaano (dato);
                  }else{
                    return vistadato (dato);
                  }
                }
              })}
            </div></div>`
          }
        }

      }
    })}

</div>


 </div>
</div>`
```

This is the error in console:

```
 TypeError: dates.map is not a function
   at module.exports (app.js:21190)
   at $.fn.countTo.options (app.js:20940)
   at app.js:14574
   at nextEnter (app.js:14406)
   at app.js:21112
```

Thanks!

Comment: Only show the code needed!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the code you provided is not exactly where the error is produced. Reading the error you are trying to map a dates Array, but the object you are receiving is not an Array and It hasn't that method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer, i edit the code again. I push all my code

Comment: At the beginning of your method try to put this: if (!Array.isArray(dates)) { dates = [];}

Comment: Hi, i resolved the problem, i use "for in" for scroll the object. Thank you very much!